# Sort several duplicate values in DataTable to one row

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I've imported a `DataTable` from a SQL Database using `SqlDataAdapter` and Fill-Method.

My datatable looks like this:

`Timestamp(unix time)   |   Value`

```
          x          |    10
          x          |    42
          x          |   643
          y          |     5
          y          |     9
          y          |    70
```

...and so on. The table contains a lot of values (1000+) but has always three rows with the same timestamp.

Now I want it to look like this:

`Timestamp(unix time)  |   Value 1   |   Value 2       |  Value 3`

```
       x             |   10    |    42   |   643
       y             |    5    |     9   |    70
```

How can I sort it this way?

(If there are more than three values, the programm should just insert the first three values it has found)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your approach! I solved it myself now.

This is how I've done it:

```
var grouped = from myRow in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
              group myRow by myRow.Field<int>("TIMESTAMP");

foreach (var timestamp in grouped)
{
    string[] myRow = new string[5];
    myRow[0] = timestamp.Key.ToString();

    int i = 1;
    foreach (var value in timestamp)
    {
      myRow[i] = value.Field<double>("VALUE").ToString();
      i++;
      if (i > 4)
          break;
    }

    mySortedTable.Rows.Add(myRow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may also be solvable in SQL, but if you want to do it programmatically, I have tested the following in LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<Tuple<string,int>> {
      Tuple.Create("x", 10),
      Tuple.Create("x", 42),
      Tuple.Create("x", 643),
      Tuple.Create("y", 5),
      Tuple.Create("y", 9),
      Tuple.Create("y", 70),
    };

    var result = 
    from grp in list.GroupBy(t => t.Item1)
    let firstThree = grp.Select(t => t.Item2).Take(3).ToList()
    select new { 
          Key = grp.Key, 
          Value1 = firstThree[0], 
          Value2 = firstThree[1], 
          Value3 = firstThree[2] };

    foreach (var item in result)
      Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

It assumes that you have **at least** three elements, otherwise you'll get an out of range exception.

While the end result is an anonymous type, you could easily pipe the results of the operation into a DataRow instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I edited my question: my example should be just an excerpt of a big table with more than 1000 values. Solvable in SQL? Would be great, but I haven't done anything in SQL yet (maybe someone can post an approach and i'll try it later)

Comment: Flq, a refinement: `Dictionary<string, List<int>> result = 
        list
        .GroupBy(a => a.Item1)
        .ToDictionary(
                      x => x.Key,
                      y => y.Select(z => z.Item2).ToList()
                     );
`