# Sort several datasets to one dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sorting

I've asked the same question some days ago, but there I wanted to solve my problem with a separate C# program. Now I want to do it in SQL directly.

[That's my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093364/sort-several-duplicate-values-in-datatable-to-one-row) (Sorry for linking you to another question)

My first attempts were to create this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myNewTrigger ON [dbo].[myTable]
FOR INSERT
AS

INSERT INTO dbo.myTargetTable
        (TIMESTAMP, VALUE_1, VALUE_2, VALUE_3, VALUE_4)
    SELECT
        DATEADD(SECOND, TIMESTAMP_S,'19700101'), VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE
        FROM inserted

GO
```

This would create four rows each with the same four values. But how can I put the values of each row in one row with different columns?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So inserted has one Value, MyTargetTable has four, and you are capturing it in a trigger????. Is TimeStamp_S guranteed tio be the same value fior all 'four inserts' Are theses inserts always in the same order, or is the order irrelevant?

Comment: I think 'inserted' does not have multiple rows. myTargetTable should have only one dataset! Yes, Timestamp is always the same for all four values. The order is always the same.  ... The four values come in four different rows with the same timestamp, but I want them to be in one row with this timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This untested Select-Statement could be your solution, if there wouldn't be a problem with the trigger.

### First problem:

The trigger is fired after every insert on mytable.
After the first insert for a Timestamp, there is just one value. So you need to update after the third or fourth record.
You do the insert for the last and not for the current timestamp. That problem is not solved in my solution.

### Second problem:

You need to make shure, that you insert only once and not after every single row.
You could add a NOT IN-Clause to the select statement for the insert.
That problem isn't solved in my solution.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT
TS
,(SELECT VALUE FROM
    (SELECT MT.TS, MT.VALUE ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY TS, VALUE) AS ROWNUMBER
    FROM myTable MT
    WHERE MT.TS = TS) DATASET
    WHERE DATASET.ROWNUMBER = 1) AS VALUE1
,(SELECT VALUE FROM
    (SELECT TS, VALUE ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY TS, VALUE) AS ROWNUMBER
    FROM myTable
    WHERE MT.TS = TS) DATASET
    WHERE DATASET.ROWNUMBER = 2) AS VALUE2
,(SELECT VALUE FROM
    (SELECT TS, VALUE ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY TS, VALUE) AS ROWNUMBER
    FROM myTable
    WHERE MT.TS = TS) DATASET
    WHERE DATASET.ROWNUMBER = 3) AS VALUE3
,(SELECT VALUE FROM
    (SELECT TS, VALUE ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY TS, VALUE) AS ROWNUMBER
    FROM myTable
    WHERE MT.TS = TS) DATASET
    WHERE DATASET.ROWNUMBER = 4) AS VALUE4
FROM inserted
GROUP BY TS
```

### Possibel Solution to your Problem, stated in the comment:

With this untested Query, you insert the last, not the current TS into the target-table. That way you make shure you just update, when the last entry of the TS is written, so you have all of the values(1..4) written, before inserting them.

It might be slow :-). But I don't know a better way.

```
SELECT 
 DISTINCT TOP 1
 TS
 ,(SELECT VALUE FROM
    (SELECT MT.TS, MT.VALUE ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY TS, VALUE) AS ROWNUMBER
    FROM myTable MT
    WHERE MT.TS = TS) DATASET
    WHERE DATASET.ROWNUMBER = 1) AS VALUE1
,(SELECT VALUE FROM
    (SELECT TS, VALUE ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY TS, VALUE) AS ROWNUMBER
    FROM myTable
    WHERE MT.TS = TS) DATASET
    WHERE DATASET.ROWNUMBER = 2) AS VALUE2
,(SELECT VALUE FROM
    (SELECT TS, VALUE ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY TS, VALUE) AS ROWNUMBER
    FROM myTable
    WHERE MT.TS = TS) DATASET
    WHERE DATASET.ROWNUMBER = 3) AS VALUE3
,(SELECT VALUE FROM
    (SELECT TS, VALUE ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY TS, VALUE) AS ROWNUMBER
    FROM myTable
    WHERE MT.TS = TS) DATASET
    WHERE DATASET.ROWNUMBER = 4) AS VALUE4
 FROM myTable
 WHERE TS < (SELECT MIN(TS) FROM INSERTED)
 AND TS NOT IN (SELECT TS FROM MyTargetTable)
 GROUP BY TS
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` could do the job. But yeah, the problem is that `inserted` probably contains only one dataset, instead of all four ones. I don't know how to check this..

Comment: @Blubb I tried to give you the solution. In my updated post. I hope it works.

Comment: Thank you very much! Basically your solution did the trick. I deleted the second to last line (`AND TS NOT...`) and added `DELETE FROM myTargetTable WHERE VALUE_1 IS NULL OR VALUE_2 IS NULL OR VALUE_3 IS NULL OR VALUE_4 IS NULL` at the end. Thank you so much for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Someone could have made this a lot easier for you...
Messy and fragile

Basically you need to

Find out if you already have a record in myTargetTable fdor the timestamp.
if not insert one setting value1.
if you do then you need to test for a free slot (values 2 to 4) and update.

If you have a ValueNumber in inserted you could do something a lot more robust.

Personally I'd be tempted to normalise this and have MyTargetTable be TimeStamp, ValueNumber, Value, though that would increase your storage requirement by three timestamps and four ints if you always get all four values. All I can say is everytime I've seen a table with Column1 to ColumnN in it, it's been when someone needed to normalise it. :(